# sed with combination of regex and literal string

Tags: regex, sed

I'm having trouble determining the pattern needed to match certain strings in a file. Here is an example:

```
#FILE="/this/is/a/file/path/" #additional comments
```

Note - /this/is/a/file/path/ is a literal string

```
sed '#FILE.*(how should the literal string be formatted here?).*/p' filename
```

Additionally, if I wanted to remove the # prior to FILE, how would the command differ? And replacing the # after removing it?

Excerpt of `cat -vte` on the file per request:

```
while [[$i -le $numberOFilesToCreate]]$
do$
^I#FILE="/this/is/a/file/path/" #additional comment
^I#FILE="/this/is/another/file/path/" #additional comment
done$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alternate regex delimiter:

```
sed 's~#\(FILE.*/this/is/a/file/path/.*\)$~\1~' file
```

Comment: This is returning the entire file to the screen.

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -vte file` in your question

Comment: Provided an excerpt. So doing `sed 's~^#\(FILE.*/this/is/a/file/path/.*\)$~\1~' file` returns all that

Comment: Same. Returns all the content of the file to the screen.

Comment: This sed command just removed `#` from `#FILE="/this/is/a/file/path/" #additional comment` line. Rest of the file remains same.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks! I added a -i so that it would edit the file as well. If I wanted the same line with the # added back, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can use `sed 's~\(^\|[^#]\)\(FILE.*/this/is/a/file/path/.*\)$~\1#\2~' file` for adding `#` back.